# Display Current Year in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the current year in Wordpress, now this is already being done in the footer template using php:

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

The site in question is for a car dealer. So there are many year model references in the page/post content ie.

```
<h1>2013 Volkswagen Polo</h1>
```

All of these need updated on the first of January each year. However the php code doesn't work within the page/post content, only in template files. So I need a different way to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: `<?php the_time('Y'); ?>` ?

Comment: `<?php echo date('Y'); ?>` works fine in the Wordpress templates, the problem is that php doesn't work in a Wordpress page/post.

Comment: @Ryan [`the_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) doesn't return the current time but the time of the post being displayed and must be used within the loop.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why don't you create the simple shortcode function for this purpose?

```
function currentYear( $atts ){
    return date('Y');
}
add_shortcode( 'year', 'currentYear' );
```

Then you will be able to put [year] to anywhere in the content area.

Comment: for what is $atts?

Answer (score 6):

A little modification of previous answer which also works fine:

in functions.php:

```
<?php
    function currentYear(){
        return date('Y');
    }
?>
```

then in footer.php (or anywhere as mentioned before):

```
<p>&copy; 2016-<?php echo currentYear(); ?> <a href="#">your_homepage_title</a></p>
```

Comment: The question specifically states they already do this, and the problem is that the WP blog WYSIWYG doesn't accept <?php tags. Creating custom [shortcode] solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following javascript to your page where you want the current year:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var d=new Date(); yr=d.getFullYear(); document.write(yr); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this function to functions.php

```
function currentYear(){
    return date('Y');
}
add_shortcode( 'year', 'currentYear' );
```

Then add the shortcode to your page.
Copyright © [year]

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin in wordpress which enables php code inside your post or content which will render perfectly and give you resul. search for exec php plugin in wordpress and add into your wordpress.

Comment: Could this be done in functions.php rather than using the plugin? I see it is no longer being updated, which makes me worry about potential security risks.

Comment: no you cant do it using functions.php because they have some parser script which parses php script and load them in a manner so that it get executed if you can do this its much better. And for using plugin why they will update that plugin for numerous time if the exact requirement is done so you can use it i have used that multiple times and i never faced any security risk till now.